# disable the click event on echarts tree chart individual node

Tags: echarts

Is there any possibility of disabling the click not to further collapse the tree or close the tree. This is the example the echarts example. See this link. I am trying this since long time. The documentation is not clear. Can anybody help me out on this? I dont want the end user to click on the circles to expand or collapse.

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=tree-radial
[image]

Comment: I fixed it by adding this property in series: [{expandAndCollapse: false,}]

Answer (score 1):

Just disable mouse events with `silent: true`.

```js
  series: [{
    //...
    silent: true,
    //...
  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a property `expandAndCollapse` inside `series`, default value is `true`. Set it to `false` which does exactly what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
series: [{
      //...
      expandAndCollapse: false,
      //...
}]
```

This is will not allow to expand or collapse any of the node in the chart.